# Retrieve Data that have same HotelID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

In my SQL Server database, there are two tables: `Room` and `Hotel`. `HotelID` is a foreign key in the `Room` table. In the `Room` table, there are 2 rooms with `HotelID = 1`.

My goal is to try to retrieve the `HotelID` in a `GET` method, then the result should show the hotel's information and the `Room`'s information that have the same `HotelID` in the `Hotel` table.

What I got from my code showed only 1 room. It supposed to show 2 rooms

```
{"item1":{"hotelID":1,"hotelName":"Dope Hotel","hotelAddress":"1234 Test St","hotelCity":"asdf","hotelState":"AB","hotelZip":"56452","hotelCountry":"USA","hotelPhone":"8081234567"},"item2":{"roomID":1,"roomName":"Ocean View","roomDescription":"This is room Description","hotelID":1}}
```

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/hotel/gethotel/{HotelID}")]
public IActionResult GetByHotelID(int HotelID, string[] roominfo)
{
        //check if the hotel ID is the same as the db hotelID
    var hotelinfo = _context.Hotels.FirstOrDefault(t => t.HotelID == HotelID);

    if (hotelinfo == null)
    {
        //if no item matches return id returning a http404 response
        return NotFound();
    }

    //return 200 with JSON response body, returning ObjectResult
    var rroominfo = _context.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(t => t.HotelID == HotelID);
    var hrinfo = (hotelinfo, rroominfo);

    if (rroominfo == null)
    {
        return new ObjectResult(hotelinfo);
    } 
    else
    {
        return new ObjectResult(hrinfo);
    }
}
```

My question is how do I get multiple rooms for my result that includes the same `HotelID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using

```
var rroominfo = _context.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(t => t.HotelID == HotelID);
```

is causing you to get only a single room. It returns the first room with the given hotel id only. Try using

```
_context.Rooms.Where(t => t.HotelID == HotelID);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Include() to load the rooms against a hotel

```
var hotelinfo = _context.Hotels.Include(x => x.Rooms).FirstOrDefault(t => 
t.HotelID == HotelID);
```